# How to change the style of dialog box items into what appears in test mode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, windows-xp

When i test my dialog box in Visual Studio 2008 by CTRL+T shortcut, i can see the dialog box items with neat slick borders. But when i compile the project and launch it via the program itself, it looks "3d" style: every dialog box has shading like old Windows 98 style.

I want to use the slick 1 pixel borders that the testing mode shows. How do i enable/disable between these two styles?

Here is example of how those two styles look like, i want to use the upper one:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STEP1 add this code to your stdafx.h:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
#if defined _M_IX86
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_X64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
#endif
```

STEP2 on method InitInstance():

```
    BOOL Ctest_stylesApp::InitInstance()
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX InitCtrls;
    InitCtrls.dwSize = sizeof(InitCtrls);
    InitCtrls.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&InitCtrls);
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and it works.

Comment: Hmm, i got it working with that, but i had to remove the `#ifdef _UNICODE`. I'm not sure why there is that line of code, but it works without it. Thanks! (I need to wait 19 hours to give the +50 bounty).

Comment: The reason for `#ifdef _UNICODE` is that the new (version 6) Common Controls library **only** works with UNICODE. There's no ASCII version of it

Comment: if `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` is defined and commctrl is not part of pre-compiled headers or mentioned anywhere yet, you'll also need to
  
`#include <CommCtrl.h>`  
  
the lib is named differently, comctl32.lib

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable ComCtl32 version 6 so that the proper visual styles will be applied to controls. Microsoft provides full instructions at this link: [Enabling Visual Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175.aspx)

Comment: i tried to use that #pragma method, but it didnt do anything, any ideas?

Comment: @Rookie, that isn't sufficient by itself, you must also call `InitCommonControls` in your program startup. I'd advise reading the entire article.

Comment: i linked to ComCtl32.lib and called InitCommonControls() but nothing is different. i dont know what else to do... it said i dont need manifests with this method, but it isnt working.

Comment: @Rookie, my mistake - you must call InitCommonControlsEx, not InitCommonControls.

Comment: i dont think i need that Ex version since im not using those classes. anyways, i tried that but cant get it work, just crashes no matter what i put into LPINITCOMMONCONTROLSEX. the weird thing is that compiler whines about uninitialized variable which i dont get. here is my code: `LPINITCOMMONCONTROLSEX a; a->dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX); a->dwICC = 0xFFFFFFFF; InitCommonControlsEx(a);` and when it didnt crash, that init func returns false.

Comment: @Rookie, try `INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX a = {sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX),0}; InitCommonControlsEx(&a);` and add individual flags in place of the `0` only if you need them.

Comment: that removed the crash, but the dialog box items are still that old style :/ i also tried with 0xFFFFFFFF to enable all flags but no effect.